# Linux SED - Hold Space - One Value to all Lines

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, sh

I would like to convert a file using sed. The Source File had following Format ('deviceId' is a Placeholder):

```
CREATE DATABASE "deviceId";
column value=88i 1445137680000000000 
column value=68i 1445137620000000000
column value=80i 1445137560000000000
column value=39i 1445137500000000000
```

After converting it, it should have following Format:

```
USE DATABASE "db";
series,device=deviceId column=88i 1445137680000000000 
series,device=deviceId column=68i 1445137620000000000
series,device=deviceId column=80i 1445137560000000000
series,device=deviceId column=39i 1445137500000000000
```

But i dont get, how i can get the deviceId in every line. My current `sed.txt` contains following code:

```bash
s/^\(CREATE DATABASE ".*";\)$/USE DATABASE "db";/g
s/\(.*\) .*=\(.*\) \(.*\)/series,device= \1=\2 \3/g
```

and generates following Output:

```
USE DATABASE "db";
series,device= column=88i 1445137680000000000·
series,device= column=68i 1445137620000000000
series,device= column=80i 1445137560000000000
series,device= column=39i 1445137500000000000
```

Can someone explain how i get the deviceId in every Line? I have seen its possible using Hold-Space/Flow-Work. I have tried it, but i dont get how this should work.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it need to be sed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $deviceId = ""; 
while( my $line = <STDIN>) {
  chomp($line);
  if($line =~ m/CREATE DATABASE/) {
    $deviceId = $line;
    $deviceId =~ s/CREATE DATABASE "(.*)"/$1/;
    print('USE DATABASE "db";' . "\n");
  }
  else {
    $line =~ s/(.*) .*=(.*) (.*)/series,device=$deviceId $1=$2 $3\n/g;
    print($line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i need. `\3` is only the Timestamp of the current line. What i need is the deviceId from the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the wrong tool. While you CAN, I expect, come up with some magical runes to force sed to produce the output you want, for robustness, portability, simplicty, efficiency, and almost every other desirable attribute of software, the standard UNIX tool to use for anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines is awk:

```
$ awk -F'["=]' '
    NR==1{dev=$(NF-1); $0 = "USE DATABASE \"db\""}
    NR>1 {$0 = "series,device=" dev " column=" $2}
1' file
USE DATABASE "db"
series,device=deviceId column=88i 1445137680000000000
series,device=deviceId column=68i 1445137620000000000
series,device=deviceId column=80i 1445137560000000000
series,device=deviceId column=39i 1445137500000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re '1h;1cUSE DATABASE "db";' -e 'G;s/.*value(.*)\n.*"(.*)".*/series,device=\2 column\1/' file
```

This stores the first line in the hold space (HS). Changes the first line to the required format. Then on every line following the first: appends the stored first line and using pattern matching and backreferences massages the line into the required format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the hold buffer very often, so I thought provide a sed solution for practice:

```
/^CREATE/ {
    # strip everything surrounding deviceId
    s/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/

    # copy to the hold buffer
    h

    # replace pattern buffer with USE ...
    s/.*/USE DATABASE "db";/
}

/^column/ {
    # append the hold space to the pattern buffer
    # this adds a leading newline which we'll use to capture deviceId
    G

    # capture the 1st field, value of the 2nd, the 3rd field,
    # then the appended deviceId after the newline
    s/\([^ ]*\) .*=\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)\n\(.*\)/series,device=\4 \1=\2 \3/
}
```